# What data type should I use to store an IP Address?

Tags: iphone, ip-address

I suddenly just thought of this and got stuck deciding which data type should I use to store an IP Address?

I have thought of `NSString`; But if I would need the last digit for identifications, should I use float or double? And that is also another problem, since when can float or double have more than 1 decimal point?

I am probably asking the question wrongly, because I really don't know how to ask this.

The IP Address comes from an XML format `<IP>192.168.1.1</IP>`. Any idea how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `NSString`.** You are not going to do arithmetic with it. If you need the separate components you can use `NSArray`, but `NSString` will serve you well for just storing the IP address.

In response to your needs, you can always obtain the last character in your string using the `NSString` method:

```
NSString *lastCharacter = [ip_string substringFromIndex: [ip_string length] - 1];
```

Where ip_string is the string holding the IP address.

**Edit in response to comment:**

Logan's code is storing each element in the IP address separated by a period into an array. So if the IP address is 192.168.1.1, the array will equal (192, 168, 1, 1).

My code is storing the entire IP address in a string, and then obtaining the last character in that string. `[ip_string substringFromIndex: [ip_string length] - 1]` is just obtaining the last character in the string containing the IP address. The last character can be found at  minus one character.

So if the IP address is 192.168.1.1, the `lastCharacter` string will just contain the number `1`.

I suggested that code because you stated that you needed to do something with the last character in your IP address string, and my code shows how you can obtain the last character.

Comment: What is the difference between your line of code and @Logan Serman's one? I can understand what Logan Serman's code means, but yours I have never seen before.

Comment: See my edited response. In summary, it is just obtaining the last character in your IP address string.

Comment: Ah! That is some awesome method! Thanks man! Gotta test this out! That method returns a NSString value right? So if I need integer value, I gotta apply the `[lastCharacter integerValue]` method right?

Comment: is a good approach, but don't forget that IPs can have more than one digit in the last number..
see Logan answer..

Answer (score 1):

Use a string. You don't need to perform arithmetic on the IP do you?

Comment: For now, I do not know if I need to do any arithmetic or algorithm. Probably not. :) Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

It is typical to store IP addresses as strings, or arrays of integers. Another option is to store it as a 32 bit integer. It really comes down to what you want to do.

Comment: Array of integers sounds like a good idea. But do you store 4 digits in 1 array? Or you store the entire IP Address, cos if you do, isn't is the same as storing it as an NSString?

Comment: @Melvin Lai: The two ways are: `var array = int[] {192,168,0,1}; //Or reversed` and `var i = 192 << 24 + 168 << 16 + 0 << 8 + 1;`. By storing it as a 32 bit integer you minimize your required storage space and have a handing value for indexing purposes as well. The array simply gives you simplistic access to the integer form if you need it (say you are doing a mask based filter but don't want to use bit logic to get out the 168). Note that in all cases, unless you are doing something quite complicated, the string form is probably best from a simplicity standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NSString`. If you need to get it piece by piece, use:

```
NSArray *pieces = [ipAddress componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
```

Comment: Thanks! Seeing so many answers, I guess all replied the same data type. Store as a `NSString`. But seeing your code, I guess that would work out well too! :)

Answer (score -1):

192.168.1.1 is considered the default IP for numerous home high-speed wireless routers. It had been initially utilized by Linksys and yet has been seen used in a number of other home network products including some of those manufactured by Netgear and also Westell among others.

Even though [IP address](http://www.192168ip.com/192-168-1-1/) stands out as the default ip for a lot of high speed broadband wireless routers, this does not essentially has to be. A large number of producers set the default IP address to 192.168.1.1 as a way to market a standard precessing conditions and to make it simpler for very first time clients to setup their own networking systems simply and efficiently.

May only Linksys as well as other wireless routers operate using the 192.168.1.1 IP?

Certainly no, given that 192.168.1.1 is definitely a non-public IPv4 address, any type of laptop or computer, modem, switch, or another web system might be devised to work with this unique IP. Nonetheless, it's not in most cases advisable because there are lots of products which default to 192.168.1.1 which in turn interaction issues can occur soon after from many different products utilizing the same IP. It's also really important to consider that a single network equipment might have just one single Ip, if you own numerous units using [private IP address](http://www.intelligentmag.com/192-168-1-1/), basically at least one has to be adjusted to an alternative location.

Comment: Do you have ANY idea what you are answering? This is a programming question, not some router question. Most of us on this site know what routers are, which brands there are and what it does. Please remove this answer as it totally does not fit this question.